# MySQL SELECT from PHP

Tags: php, mysql, email

I have one table ( members ) and five columns ( username , password , FirstName , LastName , Email )

I need to get the Email for the user admin. How would this be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT Email FROM members WHERE username = 'admin';
```

Comment: Ok. I think this is working, but how would I display the address on the page?

Comment: You have to execute the query and assign the result to a variable.  There are the `mysql_query` set of functions, but the best option is to use `PDO`.  This is an excellent resource: http://www.phpro.org/tutorials/Introduction-to-PHP-PDO.html

Answer (score 0):

Do you know what the username is of the admin? If so you can do the following:

```
SELECT `Email`
FROM `members`
WHERE `username` = {$username}
```